# PHP Trim Multiple Spaces In Between the content

Tags: php

The Content is generated dynamically based on the php conditions .

### Sample Content With Multiple White Space ( View Source )

```
<title>Samsung   Phones Under Rs.20000 </title>
```

How Title is Generating:

```
$conditional_title = <?php echo $brand; ?><?php echo $os; ?> Phones <?php echo ($prRange !='') ? 'under Rs.'$price' : ''; ?>

<title><?php echo $conditional_title; ?></title>
```

So If $os condition Fails , the content is generated with multiple white spaces , How can i trim these multiple white spaces in between the content.

### Expected Output :

```
<title>Samsung Phones Under Rs.20000 </title>
```

Comment: just trim the `echo trim($os)` ?

Comment: trim only filters before and after the content.

Comment: That's invalid PHP syntax to start with

Comment: @DarkBee apologies, I meant the brand as the `$os` isn't set...

Comment: @Darren No worries :P

Comment: `$conditional_title = $conditional_title.trim();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$conditional_title= preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $conditional_title);
```

That should do the trick, trims all excess whitespace into a single space

Answer (score 0):

You may use function trim(). http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php

```
<?php
$brand = trim($brand);
$os = trim($os);

$addition = '';
if($prRange != '')
    $addition = 'under Rs.'.$price;

$conditional_title = $brand.' '.$os.' '.Phones.' '.$addition;
?>

<title><?php echo $conditional_title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a variable is not empty:

```
$conditional_title = (!empty($brand)?$brand:"").(!empty($os)?$os:"")." Phones ".($prRange !='' ? 'under Rs.'$price' : '');

$conditional_title= preg_replace( '/[ ]+/', ' ', $conditional_title);//removing extra space if there is still any.?>

<title><?php echo $conditional_title; ?></title>
```

Well I can not understand Why are you making multiple opening and closing of `<?php ?>` in

```
$conditional_title = <?php echo $brand; ?><?php echo $os; ?> Phones <?php echo ($prRange !='') ? 'under Rs.'$price' : ''; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$conditional_title = <?php echo (isset($brand))?$brand:''; ?><?php echo (isset($os))?$os:''; ?> Phones <?php echo ($prRange !='') ? 'under Rs.'$price' : ''; ?>

<title><?php echo $conditional_title; ?></title>
```